# Calculating the trimming parameter when constructing an additive phylogeny

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, trimming

How do you calculate the trimming parameter when constructing an additive phylogeny?

I think it has a relationship with the length of the shortest hanging edge, but I can't figure out how this works.

Comment: I would assume using the trimming parameter tool, 
TreeTrimmer https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3637088/